# Counter in script for Button press not updating the score after first Button press

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a unity script for a game I'm making where if you press a button, and the image there is a certain image, it should update the score. However, the score is only being updated after you click the first button, and then subsequent button presses still remove the image from the button, but the score is not being updated. I'm not sure what's going on here. Here's the script I'm working with:

By the way, there are 9 buttons and they are all assigned the same script. I'm not sure if that's important.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine;

public class UpdateImage : MonoBehaviour {

    public Button button;
    public Sprite noImg;
    public Sprite nug;
    public Text score;
    public int score_int = 0;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        button = GetComponent<Button>();
        button.onClick.AddListener(UpdateImageTask);
    }

    void UpdateImageTask()
    {
        //button = GetComponent<Button>();
        if(button.GetComponent<Image>().sprite == nug)
        {
            score_int++;
            score.text = score_int.ToString();
        }
        button.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = noImg;

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

Comment: This question is about C#, not [UnityScript](https://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/UnityScript_versus_JavaScript) (a Javascript derivative created for Unity).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not well described but let me try to highlight something.

The below says, check if `button.GetComponent<Image>().sprite` equals `nug` and if so increment `score_int`, and replace `score_text` with the new `score_int`. And then after, replace the image `button.GetComponent<Image>().sprite` with `noImg`.

```
void UpdateImageTask()
{
    //button = GetComponent<Button>();
    if(button.GetComponent<Image>().sprite == nug)
    {
        score_int++;
        score.text = score_int.ToString();
    }
    button.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = noImg;

}
```

Note: The image will remain being `noImg` even if the `if` statement is not processed. So since the `if` statement is the potion that involves updating the score, it won't work. the `if` statement will always return false after he first button click because you have changed the image from `nug` to `noImg`. So to make it work, somehow there must be a process of chaning the image back to `nug` so that the `if` statement could run and update the score.

Comment: I'm still working on the code for generating the images. Is the issue that my score_int variables are different in each script so they all equal 1 after I press them all away? I do not have code that works to test what happens after I press the image away. That's going to take some time so I'm just trying to get the score to work for now.

Comment: Well, my answer explains it. The score only increases to 1 because the first time you press the image is nug and then changed to noImg. So when you press the button again, the if statement will not run because the image is no longer equals to nug so the score will not increase and will remain as 1. until the image equals to nug again.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the issue. The issue is that score_int isn't shared when you post the file to each button. You are only increment the score to 1 each time. To fix this, you can instead parse the score from the text box and increment that.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine;



public class UpdateImage : MonoBehaviour {

    public Button button;
    public Sprite noImg;
    public Sprite nug;
    public Text score;
    public int score_int = 0;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        button = GetComponent<Button>();
        button.onClick.AddListener(UpdateImageTask);
    }

    void UpdateImageTask()
    {
        //button = GetComponent<Button>();
        if(button.GetComponent<Image>().sprite == nug)
        {
            score_int = System.Int32.Parse(score.text);
            score_int++;
            score.text = score_int.ToString();
        }
        button.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = noImg;

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a value "shared" between all instances of a certain type then what you want is a [`static`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static) field:

```
public static int score_int = 0;
```

Now this value always is the same for each instance of your button without having to parse anything forth and back!